# SelectedNodeChanged of the treeview control not working after putting it inside a jQuery tab?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, treeview

I am developing a website using ASP.NET and used jQuery to implement the tabs in the page.

I got the design perfectly. but problem is I have a treeview on each tab. When user click a node the page should redirect to another page. Currently I am using response.redirect method which worked perfectly. But after I put the treeview control inside this jQuery tab post back occurs but instead of redirecting again it loads the same page with the tabs. I put a break point on SelectedNodeChanged event of the treeview but compiler even didn't reach to the breakpoint. What went wrong?

Here is the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>


<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Test1</a></li>

        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-1">
                        <asp:TreeView ID="tvTest" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvTest_SelectedNodeChanged">
                            <NodeStyle CssClass="tree" />
                        </asp:TreeView>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the selectednodechanged event

```
 protected void tvTest_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Response.Redirect("~/Display.aspx",true);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `tvTest_SelectedNodeChanged` function? Also, anything you're doing in `Page_Load` or `IsPostBack`

Comment: @ Jmoreland91.  This code worked fine before I put that treeview inside the jqery div tabs. For your concern I edited my question.

Comment: I am assuming that this treeview is not on Display.aspx

Comment: I didnt get it.. In Page 1 I have this tabs with treeview. All I want to do is when user click a node the page should go to Page 2. If I comment out the tabs this is working. But inside the tabs its not working. Again loading the same page.

Comment: Okay, then I am not sure what you're asking? On your node change event, it will redirect to Display.aspx, but your treeview and jquery tabs are on this page? I will post my code that works in an Answer.

Comment: Oh I am really sorry. Thank you for your effort. I accidentally disabled viewstate on the page. I re enabled it and it works fine. I dont know whats up with it. But now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

These are my Test pages. When the node changes, I.E. I click on a different node, it redirects me to the said page.

TreeView.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TreeTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.TreeTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Test1</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <asp:TreeView ID="tvTest" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvTest_SelectedNodeChanged">
                <NodeStyle CssClass="tree" />
                <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Test1"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Test2"></asp:TreeNode>
                </Nodes>
            </asp:TreeView>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

TreeView.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public partial class TreeTest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void tvTest_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Display.aspx", true);
        }
    }
}
```